# powercli remove empty folders from vcenter

Tags: powershell, vmware, directory, is-empty, powercli

i have been searching for quite some time and i cant seem to find anything close.
i am working on automating our VM for our DEV & QA dept using VCAC.
i have reached the point that during VM creation a folder with the project's name is created under the dept (for exaple  DEV\Upgrade1)

the problem starts when the DEV guys decides to delete t the whole project and start over.
i am left with a lot of empty folders throughout the VC server and i was wondering if there is a powercli script i can run daily to check if there are any empty folders (with no vms) inside and delete them if they exist.

its a tricky issue because i found i can use remove-folder but only if i give its name which i dont know.
and i dont want to delete folders with VMS inside.
anyone can help me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your already connected to your server and in powercli run this.

```
$folders = get-folder
Foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
if((get-folder $folder|get-vm).count -eq 0)
{
 remove-folder -folder $folder -confirm $false
}
}
```

Drop a -location $datacenter onto the first get-folder if you want to isolate.

Comment: thanks. but when i ran this script , it didnt do anything. so i tried to just echo the output of the folder list. (replaced remove-folder with echo $folder) but nothing happened

Comment: the correct sintax is. 

$folders = get-folder -type VM
Foreach ($folder in $folders)
{
if((get-folder $folder|get-vm) -eq $null)
{
remove-folder -folder "$folder" -confirm $false

}
}